# app crash when increase and decrease buttons are pushed

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons for the quality. If the quality is set by typing first, the buttons work well, but if I don't write any quantity and I want to set it by plus button, the app crash.

```
        increaseQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String textQuantity = quantity.getText().toString();
                givenQuantity = Integer.parseInt(textQuantity);
                quantity.setText(String.valueOf(givenQuantity + 1));
            }
        });

        decreaseQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String textQuantity = quantity.getText().toString();
                givenQuantity = Integer.parseInt(textQuantity);
                //To validate if quantity is greater than 0
                if ((givenQuantity - 1) >= 0) {
                    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(givenQuantity - 1));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(EditorActivity.this, R.string.quantity_no_less_then_0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you post crash logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround all your parsing lines with `try/catch`, like:

```
try {
    givenQuantity = Integer.parseInt(textQuantity);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    givenQuantity = 0;
}
```

when the EditText is empty, a `NumberFormatException` is thrown because an empty string can not be parsed to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

check is edittext is empty or not. If empty show toast message to user asking to enter some value to calculate.